# Is it possible to pass validatedBy attribute to the annotation as a parameter?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-validator

I hard coded the validatedBy value as following.

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = ReminderValidator.class)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyValidator{
    String message() default "{error.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Instead of hard coding the validatedBy value into my annotation interface, I want to pass it as a parameter something similar to the following.

```
@MyValidator(validatedBy = "ReminderValidator.class")
public class Reminder {
...
}
```

This will enable me to create just 1 annotation for all class validations. I will just provide different validator classes to the annotation to validate different classes. Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: I have tried giving a possible solution. Let me know if this works for you. Seems an interesting problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add multiple validators in the `@Constraint` annotation and it will pick the appropriate based on the object type.

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = { ReminderValidator.class, PendingValidator.class } )
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyValidator{
    String message() default "{error.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And

```
@MyValidator()
public class Reminder {
    ...
}

@MyValidator()
public class Pending {
    ...
}
```

Validator Examples

```
public class ReminderValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyValidator, Reminder> {
...

public class PendingValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyValidator, Pending> {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if this is an acceptable solution for you -

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = CommonValidator.class)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyValidator{
    // this decides what actual validator we will use
    String validator();
    String message() default "{error.message}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Now in the `CommonValidator` we can decide the actual validator based on the value of `validator`.

---

Example of a static validator:

```
public class SomeValidator {
    public static boolean isValid(Object field, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // your actual validation code
    }
}
```

Similarly you can define your other validators as well.

---

This is how you can use the static validator in actual validator :

```
public class CommonValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyValidator, Object> {

    private String validator;

    @Override
    public void initialize(MyValidator myValidator) {
        this.validator = myValidator.validator();
        // do other inits as per your requirement
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object field, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        ValidatorFactory.getValidator("someValidator").isValid(field, context)
        // return other validators like above
        return false;
    }
}
```

finally you can use you annotation like this -

```
@MyValidator(validator = "someValidator")
private Object object;
```

> Object can be any other class as well, you have to handle this in
>   individual static validator.

**FYI** - this is just an idea, Actual implementation might differ as per your use case.

Comment: This will require me to add an if statement to the CommonValidator class each time I create a new validation. That's why it is not exactly what I need. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: `If` is just an example ,This is where you can use a factory which will return the actual validator class based on validator name.